# Buttons to change classes with AngularJS ngClick and ngClass

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Essentially I am trying to get buttons to set `ng-class` on a div. The buttons are created from an array using `ng-repeat` and the array will grow over time. I based my idea for how to code this on the last example on [this page of the AngularJS documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) which does not use a function with `ng-click`. I am new to AngularJS and still trying to get away from my jQuery mindset so let me know if this is not the best method to go about doing this.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E2GB9/ - not sure why its not rendering the bootstrap 100% but it shouldn't matter..

When I use developer tools to check `ng-click` post load it looks correct: `ng-click="appliedStyle='example1'"` but clicking the button does not set appliedStyle.

html:

```
<body ng-app>
<div ng-controller="TypeCtrl">
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#source" data-toggle="tab">Test Area</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="source">
        <div class="hero-unit" ng-class="appliedStyle">
        <h1>H1 Header</h1>
        <h2>H2 Header</h2>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  

    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="style in styles">
            <span>Name: {{style.name}}</span><br>
            <span>H1: {{style.h1}}</span><br>
            <span>H2: {{style.h2}}</span><br>
            <span>P: {{style.p}}</span><br>
            <button class="btn-small" type="submit" ng-click="appliedStyle='{{style.className}}'">Apply {{style.name}}</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
        The Applied Style is : {{appliedStyle}}
</div>
```

js:

```
function TypeCtrl($scope) {

$scope.styles = [
    {name: 'Example 1', h1:'32px', h2:'24px', p:'12px', className:'example1'}];
}
```

css:

```
.example1 h1{
font-size:  10px;
color: red;
}

.example1 h2{
font-size:  8px;
}

.example1 p{
font-size:  6px;
}
```

Comment: BTW, `The Applied Style is : {{appliedStyle}}` stays out of controller. Put it into `div`

Comment: @MaximShoustin forgot I left that in there and was just confusing myself about it until I read this and was like "oh duh". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scope' `$parent` and this syntax:

```
ng-click="$parent.appliedStyle=style.className"
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/E2GB9/1/

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes
Basically, ng-repeat creates a new scope for each item it repeats over. Since your expression "appliedStyle='{{style.className}}'" (this can just be appliedStyle=style.className, btw) is being evaluated in one of these new scopes, it will be assigned only on the child scope. If you wanted to fix this you could put appliedStyle inside of an object. obj.appliedStyle=style.className. With angular you want to always have a '.' in your bindings, otherwise you can run into trouble (like in this case).

Comment: @Cherniv Thanks! I really like the simplicity of this but hate to use `$parent` so I put it inside an object like @Adam mentioned.

Comment: @tehaaron glad if it helps ! you know , i have just pointed one of  possible solutions , you can use (or not) it as you wish :)

Comment: @MaximShoustin you're invited to take a look at Adam' comment above

Answer (score 2):

Change your controller by adding a method like this:

```
function TypeCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.styles = [
        {name: 'Example 1', h1:'32px', h2:'24px', p:'12px', className:'example1'}];
    } 

    $scope.applyStyle = function(style) {
        $scope.appliedStyle=style.className;
    }
}
```

Then simply do this in your code:

```
<button class="btn-small" type="submit" ng-click="applyStyle( style )">
```

The long answer is that javascript with an embedded {{ }} isn't a valid expression because ng-click is using $parse service which doesn't handle {{ }} syntax.  I'd just use functions because you want to put your code in Javascript and out of your templates.  Keep your code separated.

Comment: The answer resolves the problem but the explanation is not correct. Ng-click doesn't use an isolate scope, nor is there an isolated scope anywhere in the example. Ng-repeat does create new child scopes for each item, though, and since his previous expression was being evaluated on a child scope, the value was being assigned on the child scope and not on the controller scope as you would expect. This is a good solution otherwise.

Comment: @chubbsondubs Thanks for the response. This is actually exactly what I had before reading the AngularJS docs and seeing the example that didn't add a new function. I may end up back on this route as things get more complex.